# "This" keyword does refer the current object with lamda

Tags: javascript, lambda

Consider this code:

```
var obj = {
   method : function(){
      console.log( this ); // This prints the **obj** correctly
   }
};
```

And the same code with Lambda:

```
var obj = {
   method : () => {
        console.log( this ); // This prints **Window** object
    };
};
```

Why are the outputs different?

Comment: "An arrow function does not create its own this, the this value of the enclosing execution context is used." In this case (no pun intended), the context is the `window` object.

Comment: @Terry I don't get the pun... 

Comment: @evolutionxbox "In `this` case..." get it? `this`? :)

Comment: @terry  wow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ES6 arrow function syntax uses “lexical scoping” to figure out what the value of “this” should be. Lexical scoping is fancy way of saying it uses “this” from the surrounding code… the code that contains the code in question, hence it is

> window

here.

Comment: It's a mystery what value you see in regurgitating rudimentary information about arrow functions which is documented in thousands of pages of documentation, intros, tutorials, blog posts, specs, and SO questions.